# Count and limit the number of users on my app

Tags: php, session, usage-statistics

I need to implement a system to limit the number of users that can concurrently use my app. I am thinking the best way to go is to count the number of sessions currently active and then limit based on that.

How can I count the number of sessions currently active. I am using memcached to store my sessions if that makes a difference

Comment: Are the users logging in using a user name?

Comment: It is a facebook app so... no... but there is an authentication so... I assume the answer you are looking for is yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to intercept the session's `open`, `destroy` and `gc` callbacks (using [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler)) and increment/decrement a session count value within memcached. Something like:

```
class Memcache_Save_Handler {

   private $memcached;

   public function open($save_path, $name) {
      $session_count = (int)$this->memcached->get('session_count');
      $this->memcached->set('session_count', ++$session_count);
      // rest of handling...
   }

   public function destroy($id) {
      $session_count = (int)$this->memcached->get('session_count');
      $this->memcached->set('session_count', --$session_count);      
      // rest of handling...
   }

}
```

Comment: This would be a good solution... but I would have no way to know when a session is destroyed... The users will never log out... their session will just time out....

Comment: The `gc` callback was left out of my example, but that's probably the one you are looking for. It accepts the max session lifetime as an argument. You can then compare the lifetime with the actual session modification date, and apply the same principle if it has expired. See php.net/session_set_save_handler for examples.

Comment: I assume you mean something similar to http://uk3.php.net/session_set_save_handler#58071 I am confused however as to where this session handler goes. Is it to be included at the creation of each session? When the garbage collector runs how does it know to execute that function? Sorry for being a n00b - thanks for your useful advice :)

Comment: The garbage collector knows to execute that function because you issued a session_set_save_handler() call. Remember that you will also have to provide callbacks for write, read, etc. Basically, you won't be using the memcache session.save_handler anymore, but a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to count every active sessions at a given time in PHP. I've always used a database for this, where I'd store the IP address and the current date (NOW() SQL function). Then, I you can do a query like this (MySQL syntax) :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as active_users
FROM logged_users
WHERE last_action > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
```

You can then choose to display the page or forbid the user to see the website.

Comment: How would I tell if they were still active? surely this will only tell me when they were authenticated...

Comment: Notice the WHERE condition. It's about the last_action, not the first time seen.

Comment: But that would mean I would have to update the database everything the user did something... seems inefficient to me.

Comment: Something has to be updated anyway. You can easily update every 2 minutes instead of after any action. Plus I don't say my method is the best and should absolutely be used, it's just a way to get things done.

Answer (score 1):

May be you web-server can limit maximum number of concurrent clients? (But this can affect fetching images/other static content)